# Ideals Containing Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have the following problem that I am stuck on:

Consider the ideal $I=\left\langle X(X+1)^{2}\right\rangle$ of $\mathbf{Q}[X]$. How many ideals $J$ of $\mathbf{Q}[X]$ are there such that $I\subseteq J$?

I am completely lost on this problem. I feel like it should have a straightforward solution, but I am not seeing it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Consider the ideal $I= \langle 2 . 3^2 \rangle$ of $\mathbb{Z}$. How any ideals $J$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $I \subset J$ ?

Comment: There is the mantra: "to divide is to contain".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\mathbb Q[X]$ is a [principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain), i.e. every ideal in $\mathbb Q[X]$ is generated by a single element.  If the ideal contains $I$, what could that element be?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
$$ \mathbf Q[X]/\bigl(X(X^2+1)^2\bigr)\simeq\mathbf Q[X]/(X)\times\mathbf Q[X]/\bigl((X^2+1)^2\bigl)\simeq\mathbf Q\times\mathbf Q[X]/\bigl((X^2+1)^2\bigl) $$

Comment: Oh! yes. Thanks for pointing it!